# Software to batch crop pictures

Tags: windows, image-processing

I converted about 200 pictures from RAW format and after converting I realized that the pictures had a pink line going down the entire right side of the picture ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atCyv.jpg)). Even though its small, it can still be noticeable. Its like this for all 200 pictures.

Assuming all pictures have the same dimensions, I am looking for software that can auto crop 200 pictures the same way.

Requirements:

- Must be able to batch convert all 200 pictures at the same time
- Must be able to read from .JPEG and .JPG formats
- Must have an easy to use interface (I don't want to manually input cropping dimensions for each 200 pictures)
- Should be gratis (free) but not a requirement. Open source is nice as well
- Should be able to choose either to override the original or output to a different directory (I'll be fine with either but at least one of these options must be in place)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[ImageMagick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) is a library and program suite for image display and manipulation. If you can name a raster image format, ImageMagick supports it. It's open source. You can download [Windows binaries](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows).

There are several [command line tools](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php), including [`mogrify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) which applies various transformations to an image file (overwriting the input file) and [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) which can convert between image formats and apply various transformations as well (with the output going to a new file).

To remove a rectangle at the edge of an image, [shave](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop) it [with a negative offset](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_neg_offset). To modify files in place:

```
mogrify -crop -42+0 *.jpg
```

To output files in another directory, you can use [percent escapes](http://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php):

```
convert *.jpg -crop -42+0 elsewhere\%t.%e
```

There may well be a way to let it detect the width of the pink strip automatically, but that's too advanced for me.

Answer (score 17):

If you prefer a GUI option, [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) is a free and lightweight graphics viewer with some powerful functions. It includes the ability to batch convert files. You can find the option under the `File` menu or by using the shortcut key <kbd>B</kbd>.

[image]

Then you can add all the files in a directory or import the filenames from a text file. To crop the images, select `Batch conversion` or `Batch conversion - Rename result files` if you also wish to rename the pictures. Then, check the `Use advanced options for bulk resize` box and click the `Advanced` button.

[image]

Check the `CROP` box, and fill in the values you wish to trim. I suggest you perform a test run on one image to verify your numbers first. Hit `OK`, select an output directory (or you can first choose to `Overwrite existing files` by checking the corresponding box under the `MISCELLANEOUS` section), then click `Start Batch`.

Note that the `Auto crop borders` option only works on white and transparent background. It would be useful if you could recreate the images with a white strip instead of pink.

Answer (score 4):

If all pictures are the same size you can try [FastStone Photo Resizer](http://www.faststone.org/FSResizerDetail.htm). Inter alia, it has a crop function.

I found this tool very usefull for working with batches of images some time ago.

It's a commercial application at ~20 USD.

Comment: It's "Free for Home Users".

Answer (score 3):

[BatchPhoto](http://www.batchphoto.com/) meets all your requirements (besides free) and works on Win & Mac:

- Can batch convert thousands of images and takes advantage of multi-code CPUs to speed up the process
- Reads 170 different image formats, including almost all RAW formats (JPG & JPEG is the same format)
- It has a very easy to use interface with drag & drop (see below)
- It's paid and has a free trial, but not a Windows 95 like interface or adware/spyware or bugs
- You can overwrite the originals, output to a different directory, replicate the folder structure

[image: crop multiple images at once]
[image: batch crop images]

If you use this software regularly you will do yourself a favor and pay (a small amount) for an easier to use and overall better solution than to get a free program that makes you lose time and is not enjoyable to use.

As you know nothing is free and if you choose a "free" program it will also come bundled with some "niceties" be it adware/spyware, bugs or a Windows 95 like interface. Because we (the developers) also have to make a living out of our work.

So here is my paid solution (with free trial):

[www.batchphoto.com/howto/crop-pictures.html](http://www.batchphoto.com/howto/crop-pictures.html)

Answer (score 2):

Of course, if you have access to Photoshop, you could create a simple Action to crop X pixels off of the right side of an image, then run a batch process with that action on your entire folder of images.

Clearly a higher-ticket way to handle it, but if you or someone in your office already has Photoshop, it should be a pretty quick matter.