# Scanner Software That Auto Crops Scanned Image

Tags: image-processing, scanning

I have a Dell V313w all-in-one printer that I would like to use to scan a very large number of images that are about the size of a postcard. Unfortunately the software that comes with this printer scans the image but requires you to manually crop out the white-space. This would become very tedious if I had to do this for everyone of the thousands of images I need to scan. The images aren't always the same dimensions so a default size crop etc. won't work. I have considered editing the images after scanning them but that would add a lot of extra work to this project that I would like to avoid if possible.

Is there any software (preferably free but I would also consider paid) that would be able to scan an image and automatically remove the white space around the outside?

If it could also scan multiple images at once and separate the images into separate files automatically that would be ideal.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I have considered editing the images after scanning them but that would add a lot of extra work to this project that I would like to avoid if possible.` Not if you consider a batch processing tool to crop them all in one go. You can find such software in the answers to [this question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10982/6834). Note that both programs (ImageMagick and IrfanView) have the option to autocrop white borders.

Comment: I would prefer it to be done automatically upon scanning an image however if no such software exists (that will work with my scanner) then this is a good alternative, thank-you very much for the suggestion. :)