# Crop and de-skew scans automatically - scriptable, high-volume

Tags: image-processing, document-management, scanning

I'm looking for a scriptable program (or .NET library) that I can point at a directory and say, "crop and deskew all the scans this directory, in place". (Scriptable because I have to run this on tens of thousands of directories.)

The scans may have high- or low-contrast borders; the program needs to be smart enough to leave images alone when it can't figure out the border. (And needs to be smart enough to know that if it thinks it's found the border, but cropping there would cut off 50% of the image, it hasn't really found the border!)

I've had OK results with Kofax VRS, but it seems that it can only be run at scanning time, not later. (It also slows down my sheet-fed scanners significantly.) BatchCrop runs later, but gives only OK results, and requires manual operation. ImageMagick seems like it might do what I want, if I had any idea what all the parameters actually do...

Comment: Hi Jesse. Might this question be a [duplicate of this question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25705/windows-software-to-automatically-trim-edges-of-photographs-of-documents/25714#25714) here?

Comment: @baitisj -- One key difference: no gratis requirement for me. I want the best solution, even if it's not free.

Comment: Do you mean you need to remove unnecessary "white" space around the main image? If yes, then I can recommend a program that does exactly that automatically while either running in the background or as a scheduled task with no sophisticated knowledge required.

Comment: @FitDev -- yes, though the padding around the image might not be #FFF.

Comment: @Jesse Ok. In this case I added this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Batch Image Resizer](https://www.binarymark.com/products/batchimageresizer/default.aspx). It can batch-process hundreds of images quickly - automatically in the background or as a scheduled task. It has autocrop action where it can automatically remove uniform or semi-uniform "background" from the sides you specify.

You can play around with tolerance to achieve optimal results. Here's the screenshot of that (all 4 sides are selected):

[image]

It is a commercial product though it's not very expensive and they frequently have sales.

Disclaimer: I have purchased this product sometime ago and am its paid user.